# Telescopic Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Consider the Riemann sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^n
2x^∗_k ∆x_k$$
of the integral of f(x) = 2x in an interval [a, b].

(a) Show that if $$x^∗_k$$ is the midpoint of the k−th subinterval, then the Riemann sum is
telescopic.

(b) Use part (a) to evaluate the definite integral of f(x) = 2x in [a, b].

For letter (a) I was thinking about considering $$x^*_k=a+(k-\frac{1}{2})\Delta x_k$$
But for some reason, I couldn't cancel the terms. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Suppose the $k$-th subinterval is $[c,d]$. Then $\Delta x_k=d-c$, and $x_k^*=(c+d)/2$, so that $\Delta x_k \cdot 2x_k^*=d^2-c^2$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Is this enough to prove the letter (a) and with that the letter (b) would be $$a^2-b^2$$?

Comment: Perhaps you mean $b^2-a^2$?

Comment: But wouldn't that be the case if I only considered one rectangle in the Riemann sum? Wouldn't I need to consider multiple ranges and make the terms cancel each other out?

Comment: I also believe that a^2-b^2 is wrong because considering the first interval as [a,c], then it would be c^2-a^2. Doing this up to a last interval, say [d,b], we would have b^2-d^2. So the answer would be c^2-d^2? I'm so confused

Answer (score 0):

**(a)**
Since $\Delta x_k = x_k-x_{k-1}$ and $x_k^* = \frac{1}{2}(x_k+x_{k-1})$, one has $2x_k^*\Delta x_k = x_k^2-x_{k-1}^2$, hence
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n 2x_k^*\Delta x_k = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2-x_{k-1}^2 = (x_1^2-x_0^2) + (x_2^2-x_1^2) + \ldots + (x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2) = x_n^2 - x_0^2
$$

**(b)**
Given that $x_0 = a$ and $x_n = b$, one finds in the end :
$$
\int_a^b 2x \,\mathrm{d}x = \sum_{k=1}^n 2x_k^*\Delta x_k = x_n^2 - x_0^2 = b^2 - a^2
$$